# AWS: Calling API automatically in Amazon

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I have already created an API (in C# back-end) which will be called to Push Notification on Amazon (AWS SNS).
Now I want to create a batch job that automatically calls my API (auto push notification) based on the time configuration?
I did a lot of research on this but I'm so confused on some keywords, and I don't know where to start:

- AWS Batch
- AWS Lambda
- AWS API Gateway

Can someone help to explain on this? And what I need to research to finish it?

Comment: AWS Lambda  to put the code for sending notifications. Cloudwatch to setup schedule to kick the lamda.

Comment: What @JunedAhsan said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) to put the code for sending notifications.

[AWS Cloudwatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) to setup schedule to kick the Lamda.

Suggested reading - [Tutorial: Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)

Comment: So what Amazon API Gateway does? As I researched, I will publish my API to Amazon API Gateway then connect AWS Lambda to Amazon API Gateway and finally use Cloudwatch to execute, isn't it?

Comment: You don't need to worry about API Gateway in this instance. As Cloudwatch allows you to select a specific lambda function as the target.